# Override Laravel Voyager default Image Upload Path

Tags: image, laravel, path, upload, voyager

The Voyager by default uploads the images to storage/app/public/posts folder for posts' featured images. 
I want to change it to a custom folder in my public folder.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as i can see the Voyager, you can't change the image directory since it totally depends upon the slug of the BREAD, so for example your final slug is `posts` the the directory of images will be `posts.'/'.date('F').date('Y').'/'` so you can't achive this without affecting the vendor code of voyager, try logging a github change request with voyager guys may be they will provide it in near future.

Answer (score 3):

Open `config/filesystems.php` file and check [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php#L31-L66) section. Add one more key like `voyager` for example.

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],
    'voyager' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),// change here something specific to your application need
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],
```

Then open `config/voyager.php` [file](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/master/publishable/config/voyager.php#L59-L70) and set that key (`'voyager'`) instead of 'public' like this:

```
'storage' => [
    'disk' => 'voyager',
],
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the config/filesystems.php and change the root and URL key for your new folder. See below the example

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/app', //Add new folder into public folder called app
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/app', //change get path for image 
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```